# Xpath get multiple node-names

Tags: xpath

i am using xpath to get some node names from a xhtml / xml file.

I currently have this xpath: 
`/xhtml:html/xhtml:head/xforms:model/xforms:instance/form/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'section')]`

That will get the nodes with a name like this: 
section-1_s1_partners
section-2-s2_strategy

The result of the above xpath are the matched nodes, but i want to get for each match the full-node-name. When i use the name() function like
`name(/xhtml:html/xhtml:head/xforms:model/xforms:instance/form/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'section')])`
Then it only returns the first match, and i have no clue how to do it otherwise..

Any great ideas??

Thanks!

(the xhtml/xml: )

```
<xhtml:html ....>
 <xhtml:head>
     <xhtml:title>ASD-1</xhtml:title>
    <xforms:model id="fr-form-model">
        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                <section-1_s1_partners>
                    <control-304/>
                    <toggleForm>ASD</toggleForm>
                    <applicationid/>
                    <section-345>
                        <s1_kbPaAAr/>
                        <s1_kbDCCent/>
                        <s1_kbRAE/>
                    </section-345>
                    <section-s1_depDDFentGFress>
                        <address_search/>
                        <address_postcode/>
                        <address_address1/>
                        <address_address2/>
                        <address_address3/>
                        <address_city/>
                    </section-s1_departmentAddress>
                    <section-344>
                        <s1_companyPartner/>
                        <s1_companyRegistrationNumber/>
                        <s1_companyType/>
                        <s1_companySize/>
                    </section-344>
                    <section-s1_companyAddress>
                        <address_search/>
                        <address_postcode/>
                        <address_address1/>
                        <address_address2/>
                        <address_address3/>
                        <address_city/>
                    </section-s1_companyAddress>
                    <section-324>
                        <s1_plannedDate/>
                        <s1_workDescription/>
                        <s1_publicDescription/>
                        <s1_numberOfAssociates>1</s1_numberOfAssociates>
                        <s1_duration/>
                        <s1b_resubmissionYesNo/>
                        <s1_GAAGrogramNumber/>
                    </section-324>
                </section-1_s1_partners>
                <section-2-s2_strategy>
                    <control-4/>
                    <s2_memo_strategic/>
                    <s2_memo_problems/>
                    <s2_companyPosition/>
                    <s2_companyContribution/>
                    <s2_lackExpertise/>
                    <s2_essential/>
                    <s2_companySponsor/>
                    <s2_seekKnowledge/>
                    <s2_challenge/>
                </section-2-s2_strategy>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` function need one argument, it cannot take a node list. You have to iterate over the nodelist in the language you are using. For example, in [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
for /xhtml:html/xhtml:head/xforms:model/xforms:instance/form/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'section')] 
    echo name()
```